# Having trouble configuring angular and grunt-proxy-connect.

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, proxy, gruntjs

Having trouble configuring angular and grunt-proxy-connect.
My static files are served but the web server of the proxy is never hit.
Here is the section of gruntfile.js that I am working in.
 The actual grunt server settings

```
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      proxies: [{
        context: '/', // the context of the data service
        host: 'localhost/', // wherever the data service is running
        changeOrigin: true,
        port:3000
      }],
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ],
          middleware: function (connect, options) {
            return [
          require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest,
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }

     }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you missed that part?

https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy#adding-the-configureproxy-task-to-the-server-task

In short, find this section in your Gruntfile (I assume it is generated by yeoman angular generator)

```
grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'concurrent:server',
  'autoprefixer',
  'configureProxies:server', // ... and add this line
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
```

I would also reset the proxies section to defaults:

```
  proxies: [{
    context: '/api',
    host: 'localhost', // get rid of the '/' 
    changeOrigin: false,
    port:3000 // hello, fellow Rails developer :)
  }],
```

Comment: why ```changeOrigin:false```?